# How do I fix 7zip error - Not implemented - when trying to edit a .msix file?

Tags: 7zip, msix

When I try to modify a file in a .msix package I am trying to edit, I am getting a "Not Implemented" error, followed by "Cannot update file '<directory'". I could not find anything online about this specific problem and 7zip works fine with .zips. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am following this tutorial: https://beebom.com/how-get-windows-11-paint-app-windows-10/

I tried restarting, running as administrator, and basically any other 'easy solution' on the web I could find. I also tried installing WinZip but that turned out not to work and also be behind a paywall. There was nothing else I was able to find, unfortunately. I tried using MSIX package editor on the windows store but I also need to delete some files which that software cannot do.

Comment: That tutorial is clearly telling you to **extract** the files before trying to edit and delete them. It never says to do it in place without extracting first. I think you need to carefully re-read the tutorial and make sure to actually follow along this time around. It even has pictures demonstrating that this is all done within the 7-Zip file explorer, but it's not actually within the compressed file, it's within the _folder_ that contains the _items_ that were _extracted_ from the compressed file.

Comment: edit: nvm I made a mistake, let me try that

Comment: sorry I guess I misunderstood,

Comment: It's just telling you that you can use 7-zip to _navigate_ to the _extracted_ manifest file. But you could also do it in file explorer. It's never telling you to edit the manifest file that wasn't extracted. Just follow the tutorial step by step without deviation and then see if you still have issues. Which I can practically guarantee that you will not.

Comment: "sorry I guess I misunderstood" --  no problem, and 7zip does let you edit some file types so it's an easy mistake to make.  You asked your question clearly enough to get answers, so things worked out.